# Calling function in parent from iframe, about iframe resize function

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, resize

Let's have fun with resizing an iframe from within the iframe!

So I have an html page which has some code that resizes an iframe when it loads. The javascript is in the head portion, and it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function resizeIframe(id){
/*
this.obj=obj
//this.obj.width=null
//this.obj.width=window.frames["sizeframe"].document.body.scrollWidth
this.obj.style.height="" // for Firefox and Opera
setTimeout("this.obj.style.height=this.obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+(notIE?heightOffset:0)",10) // setTimeout required for Opera
*/

el=document.getElementById(id)
el.style.height="350px" // for Firefox and Opera
setTimeout("el.style.height=el.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+'px'",1) // setTimeout required for Opera
}

// -->
</script>
```

+++ And the code for the iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe name="sizeframe" src="thoughtsinitialview.php" marginwidth="1" marginheight="1" width="596" align="middle" border="0" frameborder="0" onload="resizeIframe(this.id)" id="sizeframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no">
```

+++ The code on the inside of the iframe is all php, and there is a function within that php code that resizes a textarea box (form). That code looks like this:

```
print "<script type='text/javascript'>
function AutoGrowTextArea(textField){
    if(textField.clientHeight<textField.scrollHeight){
        textField.style.height = textField.scrollHeight + 'px';
        if(textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight){
            textField.style.height = (textField.scrollHeight * 2 - textField.clientHeight) + 'px';
        }
    }
}
</script>";
```

+++ So then, this snippit of javascript is called by the following function within the textarea like this:

```
<textarea name='reply' id='reply' rows='1' style=width: 350' onKeyUp='AutoGrowTextArea(this)'>Write a comment...</textarea>
```

+++ So...within the onKeyUp event handler, when a user adds comments that exceed 1 row, the textarea resizes! Yay: fun times! BUT - the iframe eats the rest of the displayed content that was showing when the iframe loaded. Ahhh, bummer man! :(

+++ So I added the following code to the end of onKeyUp, it looks like this:

```
parent.resizeIframe(id)
```

+++ But, it didn't work. I tried every combination I could think of, but I'm not as intelligent as the wizards hereinuponStackOverflow...

How? Do? I? make the iframe resize when the textarea resizes from user input?

Many thanks and much karmic blessings upon you in advance! (This is for the site: sitempty.org)

Comment: 1) The height in resizeIframe is not dynamic but static to 350px. 2) You can't resize your iframe if the parent's site is from different domain (same domain policy).

Comment: 1) The 350px is the starting height for the iframe, after that, it resizes.

2) Are you sure I can't resize  the iframe from within the iframe?
(I'm only asking because it's possible to call other parent javascript functions from within an iframe...)

3) any idears on a workaround?

Comment: Ok, 3) The setTimout doesn't work because the executed code is in a new (different) scope; so the local vars like `el` are not present; you should receive a javascript alert the `el` is not defined. For the parent functions call: it works if both sites are on the same domain. If not it won't.

Comment: What about the event handler "OnResize"...

Comment: Check out the "Thoughts?" page at sitempty.org...there's proof that resize iframe does work...I've been using the code since 2009...from mtmj.org to many other sites, it works. I think that maybe I didn't post all the code, so it's corn-fuzing...

Comment: I did not say that this _is_ the reason but that it _could be_ a reason.

Comment: Can I please get some help with this?

Comment: Hello? Is anybody out there?